# Why does the edit of a suggested edit reviewer not show in the post?

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, revision-history

I have edited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089912/a-strange-issue-with-redux-and-webpack) post and the corresponding review status is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12275749).

I have noticed for the first time that in the review status, the last reviewer approved my edit with some improvement. But in the original post, I am seeing that I am the last editor. Before this edit, I have faced several approved edits with improvement, but in every case, the last reviewer was the last editor of the post and there existed a corresponding history.

What did the reviewer change and where is the corresponding history?

Comment: Best guess without specific knowledge is the user clicked "Improve" which accepted your edit, but decided afterwards that your edit didn't really need improved, so aborted his edit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just reproduced on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37104591/3853934) (see [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12284277) and [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37104591/revisions)).

If a reviewer clicks <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd>, and then clicks <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> without making any changes, their edit is still submitted and looks [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37104576/revisions). However, it they clear the "Edit summary" field before submitting the edit, it won't appear in the revision history.

I think this is a bug and needs to be fixed.

Related on Meta.SE: [Low Quality Posts review task can be completed as “Edit” without actually editing the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276227/310998).

Comment: "*grammer fix*" -- oh the irony of this one always gets to me